# How to display preview image in laravel foreach

Tags: laravel, indexing, preview

How to display preview image in foreach laravel ?
I show item from query in view laravel and i want edit image for item data

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoBiP.png)

For index 0 I can show preview image, but for index 1 and so on I can't show preview image

My View Code

```
<img id="preview-image-before-upload{{ $j++ }}" style="max-height: 150px;">
<input id="image" type="file" class="form-control" name="item_img" data-target="{{ $i++ }}">
```

My Javascript Code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (e) { 
    $('#image').change(function(){
    let target = $(this).data('target');
      let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (e) => { 
        $('#preview-image-before-upload'+target).attr('src', e.target.result); 
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]); 
    
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Input tag id **image** remain same in foreach loop. As you made *preview-image-before-upload* as unique using variable, create **image{{$i++}} or image{{$i++}}** <input id="image" type="file" class="form-control" name="item_img" data-target="{{ $i++ }}">

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow fahmi. please provide a [mcve] not an incomplete excerpts (like cutting away the foreach loop). waqas is right, your you have multiple html element with `image` as id, it will cause problem. you should register the event using class instead (e.g. `$('.image-upload').change(function(){...`).

Comment: thanks, this works!. Sorry if my question writing is still bad